# Having Lubuntu and Kubuntu together

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, xorg, kubuntu

I need lubuntu to do development, but sometimes I would like to log and enjoy a richer  system as kubuntu or ubuntu, but also all the most fancy desktop environment, compiz, enlightment etc.

a virtual machine is not an option because I have an I3 processor. I would avoid to split the system in two boots if is possible and having a main LUBUNTU system.

My dream would be to go to init5 and run startx starting kubuntu with a lot of desktop environment. My challenge is that if I do something as this I am pretty sure that when I will run lubuntu, the performance will worsen a lot, daemons, .settingsfiles, libraries that will occupy ram even if I do not need, dependencies etc

there is a way i can use lubuntu and sometimes start a more demanding ubuntu version?
I thought maybe I should kind of set two different users, or install a version without graphical environment and from there launch just what i need. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's essentially three ways to do what you want:

- Set up a dual boot system. This means that Lubuntu and Kubuntu will be completely separate, on two different partitions. However, you *can* share data between them, e.g. with a shared partition for data, or by directly copying files from one partition to the other. This *may* use less resources (memory) than the other ways, but will use more disk space.

  To set this up, just install one Ubuntu flavor first (e.g Lubuntu), and then install the other one (Kubuntu). The Kubuntu installer will give you the option to install side-by-side.
- The other way to do this would be to install LXDE and KDE side-by-side, in one installation. So you could install Lubuntu, and then install KDE. You can then choose which desktop environment to start when you login. Data, applications, and so on, are shared between both desktop environments.

  This will, in fact, ***not** use significantly more resources* - if you are using LXDE, only LXDE components loaded, and the same for KDE, so you won't see a significant increase in used memory or CPU resources.

The third possibility:

- Would be to use a VM anyway - with a Core i3, and at least 3GB of RAM, it won't be a problem - I used to run Windows 7 in a VM on a Core2 Duo, with 2GB of ram, no problem. A VM would only use resources when it's running.

Comment: thanks i am really interested in the second option LXDE and KDE side by side, what i need to do is basically sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop right? and then the system will start in init5

Comment: @trocchietto, Yes, exactly.

Comment: I was thinking possibly if I maintain every desktop environment with a different user, the dependencies will remain separate and will avoid bloadsoftware. Just I have some doubt removing them the user will not remove the packages

Comment: @trocchietto AFAIK, that won't good be any performance benefits, since the desktop environment, including the dependencies and services, you install would be shared between all users.

Comment: too bad @JonasCz, I am thinking to follow  now the first solution, is the safest one, after all if things go wrong I will easily take the command of my lubuntu +android studio distro playing with grub/lilo. as far as I maintain a common partition for movies and music, I can do any fancy experiment on the second operative system! thanks

Comment: @trocchietto Unless you have a really low-end machine, with very little RAM, I wouldn't worry so much about performance. But if the dual boot works for you, that's great !

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

1. Install Xenserver and run Lubuntu and Kubuntu with hardware passthrough to each simultaneously, spinning down one or the other as necessary (I am willing to bet your i3 will actually handle this nicely)
2. Install KDE on Lubuntu and switch DEs at the login screen
3. Install Kubuntu alongside Lubuntu and dual-boot using GRUB to select your OS of choice at boot time.